# Ubuntu 16.04 VPS security - check whether installation of the OS is unaltered (clean)

Tags: 16.04, server, security

> before you go ahead, I've to inform you that I've asked this question at Aug 1st 2019 on unix.stackexchange but didn't get any appropriate response. so I've brought the whole question here, but [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533399/ubuntu-16-04-vps-security-check-whether-installation-of-the-os-is-unaltered-c) is the original place where I asked the question for your information and I encourage you to take a quick look at it. I also didn't find any related question so far. thanks in advance for your attention.

I'd ordered a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04/64-bit LTS server edition with some ports opened, which are essential to my application.

recently the VPS was delivered to me, so I accessed the VPS using ssh and changed the ssh password.

now my question is:

how can I make sure that **the Ubuntu 16.04 installation that was delivered to me**, is a clean installation and does not have any extra functionality (malicious or not) and/or extra files with respect to the original OS that Ubuntu provides publicly?

**now I have to say that I trust my VPS provider, but I have this question in general.**

unfortunately I wasn't able to find any similar question. so I would be happy, if you refer me to one.

following are more details that might be helpful.

thanks.

---

`cat /etc/os-release` output:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

---

`hostnamectl` output:

```
Static hostname: ubuntu
Icon name: computer-vm
Chassis: vm
Machine ID: *** (not shown deliberately)
Boot ID: *** (not shown deliberately)
Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-157-generic
Architecture: x86-64
```

---

`uname -r` output:

```
4.4.0-157-generic
```

Comment: Most VPS provided OSs are altered. Sometimes the kernel is different, sometimes there are additional setting, etc. With this out of the way, it remains to determine if the changes are malicious or not, which is not an easy task. There is no point and click or one command solution you might have expected for something as broad and complex.

Comment: @Moher Mike's point is: unless you've done the install from ISO yourself, you can't easily verify whether it's modified otherwise.  This is why I go with VPS providers who let me boot from ISO to do the installation myself, giving myself a 'clean' environment.  There's not much you can really *do* here though other than a side-by-side verification of the hashes of all installed files, but I can tell you with almost 100% certainty if you're on a VPS using a non-ISO image, it's 'altered' in some way, either by the host or the provider of the image to the host.

Comment: @ThomasWard, well thanks. the hash idea occurred to me also, but I think there needs to be a more straight forward way of confirming that. through out the years, I have always tried to make my VPS safer and safer, just until recently that it occurred to me, that the VPS provider can do a lot with me ever knowing about it. again your comment didn't shed any more light on the matter but thanks anyway

Comment: @Moher the problem is we can't really give you a true answer that works for all situations - we aren't the VPS providers, and if you have a hosted VPS then even if you straight install they *likely* have a backdoor into the system - you'd need to be paying for a dedicated server rather than a VPS to really have security, or purchase a server and colocate it at a data center.

Answer (score 1):

My first cut suggestion would be to compare a list of all the files using `diff`. You may be able to find a list of all the files in a default install somewhere but my, admittedly cursory, search didn't turn anything up. If you can't, you'll need to install a temporary installation of Ubuntu server with as similar a setup as you can estimate and use `updatedb` and `locate` to generate a list of all files.

```
updatedb
locate / > all_files.txt
```

Similarly you could use `find`.

```
find / > all_files.txt
```

Get these lists from both systems and then perform a `diff` between these lists to find all of the files that differ between systems. This might be really messy if the files are in a different order which is why I would suggest `updatedb` over `find` as I think `find` isn't as likely to generate the list in the same order (please correct me if I'm wrong). A review of the differences identified will tell you whether someone tried to sneak something in, or out.

Of course this won't tell you whether they changed things within the files but I would expect to see at least some new files if there was substantial deviation from the base install as would occur in an attempt to subvert the system. This isn't to say they couldn't make changes to create an intentionally insecure system but you'll likely find that as you properly secure the system anyway.

Comment: Right, it will take years to manually compare all text files in Ubuntu. Also, every update will bring changes to some files, not to mention that diff can't compare binary files. ...so, good luck with that.

Comment: To be clear, I mean to do a diff of the file lists only. On two identical systems this would tell you whether any changes were made. I admit, in this scenario it is likely still impractical.

Comment: Well, it is still unclear what are "file lists", and how it would help make sure the system is "unaltered". It is also unclear how you'd get, and ensure the two systems are, supposedly, identical.

Comment: @RaidPinata, thanks so much for your answer. but of course this is not the answer that I am looking for. as just checking files won't do any good. but you gave me this idea, that maybe we can check not only the what files are extra, but maybe check their hashes against an supposedly matching version.